# Logo on Navbar Won't Show in Laravel Jetstream

Tags: laravel, vue.js, tailwind-css, inertiajs, laravel-jetstream

So I learn Laravel Jetstream using Inertia Stack. While I was doing some changing on Logo in the Navbar on Dashboard view it's still showing.

But when I go to profile view, it's just gone, I don't know why, but if I try using blade function which is asset function, it'll be gone in dashboard view too.

This is my code on ApplicationMark.vue:

```
<template>
    <img class="block h-9 w-auto" src="favicon.png" alt="Logo">
    <!-- <img class="block h-9 w-auto" src="{{ asset('favicon.png') }}" alt="Logo"> -->
</template>
```

Comment: Try `src="/favicon.png"`

Comment: Thank you very much, I was looking for some answer for quite a while, and the problem is just this '/'? Haha, maybe should I learn more about Vue and Inertia first before jumping to Jetstream, and once again thanks @brombeer

Comment: Not really related to Vue or Inertia or Jetstream. Having a `/` at the beginning of an "asset" (image, javascript, css etc.) will load it from the topmost "root" URL of your server. _Not_ having it will try to load it from the current directory you're in